# Is making apps haram?

Tags: halal-haram, software

I was wondering if making apps is haram. For example, ones that can help with productivity or communication between groups.

Comment: Short answer: **No**

Comment: I second that, No.

Comment: You can specify a specific app that would be helpful, in general its ok to make apps, but of-course if any app supports anyone in sins, will not be ok of-course.

Comment: Maybe you could add why you think it is could be haram and what makes you ask the question? You a certainly writing this question in an "app" (or web which also is an app). Wouldn't that too be haram then?

Comment: if your niya is for Halal that its ok, else its Haram wallaho aalam

Comment: Not haram, but some apps which attract user to haram act to make such app is haram, i am also app developer by the way & would not involve on making of app/software which get user attention to haram act

Answer (score 2):

It's not the app, it's what it's used for.

This is analogous to asking *is English haram?*  There are things one can say in English which are haram to say, but the English language is not the problem.  Likewise, an app is not a problem in itself.

Many Muslims routinely use non-Islamic apps like clocks, email apps, and document readers, along with Islamic apps for e.g. prayer times and mosque locations.  Many can be found by Googling `Islam apps`, `Quran apps` etc.  Indeed, many scholars of Islam use Facebook and various social media, and presumably many of them use apps.  But, of course, there will be apps, such as gambling apps, which would be haram to make.

In the context of an FM radio app proposal, we have the following fatwa:

> In principle, **it is permissible to develop radio applications for smartphones, etc. as long as it serves an educational or religious purpose and does not entail of any sin or evil**. However, it is prevalent that its usage is predominately for the wrong purposes... it would be reprehensible for one to develop a FM radio app. -- Fahad Abdul Wahab, checked and approved by Mufti Ebrahim Desai, sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/82989) (another example is from [AskImam.org](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/28417) in the context of games)

In the context of developing an Islam "brownie point" system:

> In principle, **there is nothing wrong with setting up an electronic application**... However, the program must be regulated by the Sharee'ah and free from innovations.  -- [IslamWeb.net](http://www.islamweb.net/prophet/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=254356)

In the context of making a phone app to sell Islamic information:

> **Making these Islamic apps**... **aimed at spreading the religion of Allah, and teaching Qur’an and hadeeth, is a great and blessed good deed**... -- [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/187114)

Answer (score 0):

Lets see this in this way that you can keep a knife or a gun in your home for safety but you cannot use it for killing someone. Just like that you can develop mobile apps but for positive use.

> for example `app for selling mobile-phones is OK` but `app for selling pig is
>   haram.`Because pig is haram.