# Is creating a chat app or application haram?

Tags: halal-haram, software

I started developing a **Chat application** (something like whatsapp or Line) 2 months ago. However, due to articles that qualify Facebook, Whatsapp and the recent Pokemon Go as Haram, I really doubt if I should continue the development of my app or kill it. That is why I am seeking for your help to know if it is haram or not.

Comment: what is the reason you think it would be haraam?

Comment: if the idea is that some one will use it for haraam then cars we shouldnt working the car industry or shoe industry as we can walk to haraam or drive to it

Comment: Seems related [Is making apps haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35154/is-making-apps-haram?)

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.